# ¿Es gramaticalmente correcta la frase “antes de la tormenta viene la calma”?

Tags: gramática

He escuchado la frase "la calma antes de la tormenta" y también he escuchado la frase "después de la tormenta viene la calma" así que estaba pensando si es correcto decir “antes de la tormenta viene la calma”

Suponiendo un estado inicial de poca alteración, despues vendría un estado de calma total el cual seria el anuncio de la llegada de un estado de gran alteración(la tormenta), por lo que seria correcto decir que "antes del periodo de gran alteración viene un periodo de calma total" o por decirlo de otra manera “antes de la tormenta viene la calma”

Comment: Gramaticalmente es impecable, otra cosa es si su significado es cierto o no.

Comment: ¿Qué posible incorrección encuentras a esta frase?

Comment: La posible incorrección es por que como dice @Gustavson el verbo venir podría entenderse como una acción posterior

Comment: Yo diría:
"Antes de la tormenta hay una gran calma", y
"Después de la tormenta viene la calma".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es perfectamente válida. Suponiendo que ninguna de las dos cosas haya sucedido aún (ni la calma ni la tormenta), se puede decir:

> Antes de la tormenta viene la calma.

Del mismo modo que se puede decir:

> Antes de [llegar a] Madrid pasamos por Getafe.

En este caso estamos usando el presente para indicar un hecho que sucederá en el futuro previsto.

Comment: Exacto, todo depende si sabemos cuando sera la tormenta y la calma: Antes de la tormenta vendrá la calma (la calma aun no llega), antes de la tormenta vino la calma (ya paso la tormenta), antes de la tormenta viene la calma (no sabemos/no nos importa, o ya llego la calma pero aun no llega la tormenta)... incluso podemos usar "llegaba" si antes de la tormenta ya no llega la calma.

Answer (score 0):

Los que observan la meteorología se han fijado que para cierto tipo de tormentas, existe un periodo de calma justo antes del comienzo de la tormenta.  Este fenómeno se explica en https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/4601/13386.

Luego se generalizó el concepto y se extendió a situaciones de conflicto entre personas o grupos, o incluso cualquier gran actividad.  He aquí un ejemplo del uso de la frase:

> Cuando llegué a la casa todo estaba tranquilo.  Era un momento de calma antes de la tormenta, que se desató con la llegada de los primeros invitados.

Se podría hacer también una observación generalizada de esta manera, aunque no hace tan buen efecto:

> La tormenta viene después de la calma.

Ahora, si alguien comenta

> Después de la tormenta viene la calma

está expresando otra idea diferente.  Ahí se está diciendo que después de la bulla (ruido, etc.), las cosas se calman.   (A mí aviso esta observación es tan obvia que no vale la pena expresarla; sospecho que quienes la usan quizás no han entendido de donde viene la frase hecha.)

Comment: No se quien votó negativo pues me parece bien como respuesta aunque yo estoy en desacuerdo en que "después de la tormenta viene la calma" es una frase inútil. En inglés existe "it is darkest before dawn" que expresa más o menos lo mismo, queriendo ambas frases decir que no se pierda la esperanza que lo malo pasa y ya vendrán momentos mejores. Igual te doy mi +1 :-)

Comment: me parece que esta respuesta explica mas el significado de la frase que si es correcta o no

Answer (score -1):

El verbo "venir" en presente supone una acción posterior, no anterior, por lo que considero que la oración "antes de la tormenta viene la calma" es semánticamente confusa (no diría que es agramatical).

Para que una oración como la propuesta fuera correcta, debería utilizarse "venir" en tiempo pretérito:

- Antes de la tormenta, **vino** la calma. (o mejor: ...**había venido** la calma)

Obviamente, sería mejor utilizar un verbo más estático:

- Antes de la tormenta, **hubo/había** calma / **reinaba** la calma.

Comment: puesto que son dos oraciones separadas, creo que esto no hace diferencia 
antes de la tormenta vendra la calma tambien lo veo correcto  , incluso el caso contrario es correcto: despues de la tormenta vino la calma

Comment: la acción si es posterior es decir habla de un evento que esta por suceder