# "Estar a" en referencia al pasado

Tags: preposiciones

Hablando con un compañero de trabajo, ha surgido la frase:

> Estamos a 20 años del 2000

Él sostiene que utilizar la preposición *a* es incorrecto, ya que me estoy refiriendo a una fecha en el pasado. Según él, sí sería correcto decir:

> Estamos a 20 años del 2040

Mi argumento es que la preposición *a* indica una *distancia temporal*, independiente de si es hacia el pasado o hacia el futuro.

*¿Existe alguna otra manera de decirlo, o es correcto utilizar "a"?*

Comment: "Mi argumento es que la preposición *a* indica una distancia temporal" --> Desde luego, nuestras posturas están a chorrocientos kilómetros la una de la otra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si miramos la definición en el diccionario que atañe al caso que comentas, leemos lo siguiente:

> [**a<sup>2</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=003Ov93)
>
> Del lat. *ad*.
>
> 7. prep. Indica la situación de alguien o algo. *A la derecha del director. A oriente. A occidente.*

Si te fijas, la definición solo dice que "indica la situación". No añade ninguna restricción más, luego la situación puede ser tanto temporal, como en *Estamos a 10 minutos de casa*, como espacial, como en *Estamos a 10 kilómetros de casa*.

Si bien es cierto que en el ejemplo del caso temporal los 10 minutos están a futuro, en realidad no se indica *desde dónde* tiene que considerarse esa situación. Simplemente está indicando que, en un medio de transporte indeterminado, si se dirigieran hacia casa tardarían 10 minutos. Pero el hablante puede estar quieto, o sabe que tardarían eso porque eso es lo que han tardado en llegar hasta donde se encuentran.

Igualmente, en el segundo caso, *Estamos a 10 kilómetros de casa*, se puede implicar tanto que al hablante le faltan por recorrer 10 kilómetros para llegar a casa, como que ya ha recorrido 10 kilómetros desde que salió de casa, o como que están pasando el día en un sitio que está a esa distancia de casa, sin ir ni volver. Lo único que importa es la situación relativa: *a 10 kilómetros de casa*.

Del mismo modo, se puede argumentar que la expresión *a 10 años del 2000* puede implicar que nos estamos acercando o alejando de ese año: solo importa la situación relativa. Reconozco, en todo caso, que la expresión se suele usar más en el sentido de futuro. Si digo *Estamos a 10 kilómetros de casa*, sin más contexto yo entiendo que eso es lo que tardaríamos en llegar a casa; si digo *Estamos a 10 años del 2030* entiendo que eso es lo que nos falta para llegar a ese año, pero eso es porque conocemos cuál es el año actual. Con el contexto adecuado ambas expresiones se pueden usar con el sentido de tiempo pasado.

En todo caso, a falta de contexto yo sugeriría una ligera modificación para el tiempo pasado:

> Estamos *ya* a 10 kilómetros de casa.
>   Estamos *ya* a 20 años del año 2000.

Aunque en ese último caso el *ya* sería innecesario dado que se conoce cuál es el año actual y, por tanto, que la expresión sin más se refiere al pasado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Sintácticamente hablando, la corrección de la frase no puede depender del momento en el que se diga. ¿Podría la frase ser *correcta* (que no cierta, eso es irrelevante) en 1980 pero no serlo a día de hoy? No es una crítica a la respuesta, que me parece correcta, es simplemente un apunte ;)

Comment: @alseether opino que la frase es correcta tanto en 1980 como en 2020, ambos años están _a 20 años del 2000_.

Answer (score 4):

Este aporte es más un comentario que una respuesta, pero como se refiere a todas las respuestas creí conveniente formularlo de este modo.

Todas las respuestas me parecen debidamente justificadas pero deberíamos plantearnos qué es lo que hizo que al compañero de trabajo de alseether le resultara extraño un uso lingüístico aparentemente correcto, y creo que es el uso.

Cuando decimos "estamos a X tiempo de X evento", **normalmente** ese evento está en el futuro y el período detallado es un período que aún no ha transcurrido.

La oración en cuestión me produce un efecto de confusión similar al que recuerdo que me produjo  (y me sigue produciendo) la oración "antes de la tormenta viene la calma" en el marco de [una vieja pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26885/es-gramaticalmente-correcta-la-frase-antes-de-la-tormenta-viene-la-calma) en este sitio.

El oyente está condicionado por la experiencia lingüística a entender ciertos conceptos, y cuando las condiciones se alteran experimenta cierta extrañeza o confusión. Es un tema de pragmática, no de gramática.

Mi conclusión es que la oración:

- Estamos a X tiempo de X evento

referida al pasado es **gramaticalmente correcta** pero **pragmáticamente confusa**.

Lo normal sería decir:

- Ya pasaron X años de X evento.

Comment: @walen Acabo de ver tu intercambio con Pablo. Me siento más acompañado que cuando fue lo de la tormenta y la calma jajaja

Answer (score 2):

Dice la [*Nueva gramática*](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SeOXLjwNZFJQoRAz):

> **29.4j** Con la correlación *a... de...* se forman otras muchas expresiones temporales y locativas complejas que designan instantes o lugares: *a dos horas de aquí, a tres millas de la costa, a cuatro días de la final del Campeonato*. Sigue a la preposición *a* en estos casos un grupo nominal cuantitativo formado con algún nombre de medida espacial o temporal.
>   La preposición *de* precede, a su vez, al grupo nominal que manifiesta el punto que se
>   toma como origen del cómputo. Estas expresiones complejas se pueden sustituir por
>   adverbios de tiempo o de lugar. Así, en *Buscó al ministro Juan Briones y al general Ketín Vidal, que estaban **a dos cuadras de la residencia*** (*Caretas* 26/12/1996), se obtiene *... que estaban **allí***. También se pueden sustituir por grupos preposicionales cuantitativos (*... estaban **a dos cuadras de la residencia** > ¿**A qué distancia** estaban?*). Alternan también con adverbios que poseen complementos, sean expresos o tácitos: *Estaban {cerca ~ a dos cuadras) de la residencia*.
>
> **29.4k** El rasgo más característico de las expresiones mencionadas en el apartado precedente es el hecho de que localizan un punto en el espacio o en el tiempo. No modifican, por tanto, a los verbos de movimiento, a diferencia de las que se han analizado en los apartados anteriores. Los grupos sintácticos así construidos proporcionan dos informaciones: el punto inicial de la medición (*la residencia* en el ejemplo de *Caretas* que se acaba de citar: *... que estaban **a dos cuadras de la residencia***) y la magnitud temporal o espacial que debe medirse desde él (*dos cuadras* en ese mismo ejemplo). El primero puede omitirse si se ha presentado en el discurso previo, como en *Estamos a solo dos cuadras*.
>   En estas construcciones no se proporciona el otro punto de la medición a la que se hace
>   referencia porque constituye precisamente la noción que se identifica. De este modo, en
>   el ejemplo propuesto se identifica el lugar en el que están dos individuos (*el ministro
>   Juan Briones y el general Ketín Vidal*) a partir de la distancia (*dos cuadras*) que los separa de cierto punto (*la residencia*).
>
> **29.4l** El límite al que se alude en los apartados precedentes puede expresarse mediante un grupo preposicional o adverbial introducido generalmente por *sobre*, *bajo*, *por encima* o *por debajo*, o bien por *delante*, *detrás*, *encima*, *debajo* y otros adverbios, de forma similar a como sucedía en las construcciones analizadas en el 29.4f:
>
> > **A pocos pasos delante de mi** cayó una piedra enorme y se hundió en la tierra. (Somers, *Retrato*); **Situada a 35 metros bajo la calle de Alcalá**, fue necesario todo tipo de taponamientos y entubaciones para evitar una lluvia de agua del subsuelo sobre las reservas de oro. (*País* [Esp.] 1/2/1987); Los seres alados estaban pasando **a unos diez metros por encima de nosotros**. (Levrero, *París*).

No veo nada en estos apartados que indique que las distancias temporales así expresadas deban tener obligatoriamente un sentido *presente → futuro*.
Por tanto, tal y como lo has dicho (y teniendo en cuenta especialmente que el punto de referencia es explícito: *... del 2000*), en principio sería correcto decirlo así.

Comment: La NGLE dice "el punto inicial de la medición... y la magnitud temporal o espacial que debe medirse desde él", con lo cual no queda claro si está bien decir "a 20 años del 2000" dado que "el punto inicial" es hoy; en último término todo depende de si la forma en que visualizamos el tiempo es equivalente a la del espacio (donde no hay un eje absoluto) o bien lo vemos como una flecha orientada al futuro, con lo cual "a 20 años del 2000" sería incorrecto... OK, ya me voy. :)

Comment: @pablodf76 aun considerando el punto inicial la fecha actual, ¿no seguimos estando a 20 años del 2000? Como menciono en la pregunta, es una _distancia temporal_. La distancia, por definición es una diferencia, es decir, es igual de A a B que de B a A

Comment: @walen Coincido. La (im)posibilidad de viajar atrás en el tiempo no puede influir en el hecho de que la frase sea correcta. Sino, todas aquellas frases que describan hechos imposibles serían incorrectas, y no es lo que estamos tratando aquí.

Comment: No era mi intención polemizar con la respuesta sino plantear que la misma no es una obviedad. Depende para ser correcta de cómo reflejamos en la lengua nuestras ideas sobre el tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto tu punto, no el de tu amigo.

Por lo que preguntas, decir

> ***Estamos a 20 años del 2000***

es válido, tanto sea que los hablantes estén temporalmente situados dos décadas atrás (1980), o adelante (2020). Lingüísticamente no hay un presupuesto implícito de sentido cronologico preestablecido que haga a la frase gramaticalmente entendible hacia el futuro y no al pasado, como tu amigo sostiene.

En cuanto a qué otra manera existe de expresarlo, me parece que es lo mismo que decir

> *Distan* 20 años del 2000